# When I change the main project mxml file, then export it, the swf doesn't change, why?

Tags: apache-flex, flash

I have an existing flex project from years ago that I need to modify, I am using Flash Builder 4. When I export the project it creates an swf file in bin-release, then when I modify the code in the project mxml file or any supporting files and export it the swf should change but it does not. Do you have any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, there was an existing swf file in the html-template folder in the project. This caused it to override the new builds swf.